# BeanCreationException caused by BeanInstantiationException caused by NullPointerException: name

Tags: java, xml, spring, nullpointerexception

I am currently trying to test out a web application but I keep getting a NullPointerException whenever I try to start up Websphere 8.5, which causes the BeanInstantiationException and BeanCreationException.  I have tried playing around with the annotations and removing the beans in the mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml file but the same error keeps occuring but with a different bean.  I am unsure of what I need to change to get this running.

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.trac.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.trac.model" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Configure to plugin JSON as request and response in method handler -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
<bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
</bean> 

<bean id="agencyDao" class="com.trac.dao.AgencyDao">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
<bean id="subsidyDao" class="com.trac.dao.SubsidyDao">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
<bean id="agentDao" class="com.trac.dao.AgentDao">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
<bean id="verificationDao" class="com.trac.dao.VerificationDao">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="mainController" class="com.trac.controller.MainController">
    <property name="sessionBean" ref="sessionBean"></property>
    <property name="racfGroup" ref="racfGroup"></property> 
</bean>

<bean id="racfGroup" class="com.trac.verification.RacfGroupData">
    <property name="securityService" ref="securityService"/>
</bean>

<bean id="securityService" class="com.security.client.services.SecurityService"/>

<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/aoa" resource-ref="true"/>
```

MainController.java (where the beans are to be initiated)

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

private CompanyOrgVerification org = new CompanyOrgVerification();

@Autowired
private SessionBean session;
private RacfGroupData racfGroup;

//returns the agent search page
@RequestMapping(URIConstants.WELCOME_PAGE)
public ModelAndView welcome(HttpServletRequest request){ 

    session.setUserId("T5575");
    session.setPermission("INFOA", "U");

    if( racfGroup.getRacfGroups(session.getUserId()) ){
        session.setPermission("INFOA", "U"); 
        return new ModelAndView("index");
    }else{
        ModelAndView error = new ModelAndView();
        error.setViewName("error");
        return error;   
    }
}public SessionBean getSessionBean(){
    return session;
}
public void setSessionBean(SessionBean session){
    this.session = session;
}
public RacfGroupData getRacfGroup(){
    return racfGroup;
}
public void setRacfGroup(RacfGroupData racfGroup){
    this.racfGroup = racfGroup;
}
```

}

RacfGroupData.java

```
public class RacfGroupData {
   private SecurityService securityService;

   static{
      SystemProperties.setProperty("RacfAttempts", String.valueOf(ATTEMPTS));
      SystemProperties.setProperty("RacfServerIP", SERVER_IP);
      SystemProperties.setProperty("RacfServerKey", SERVER_KEY);
      SystemProperties.setProperty("RacfTimeout", String.valueOf(TIMEOUT));
   }
   // get racf groups for a given user ID.
   public boolean getRacfGroups(String userID){
       GroupLookupResponse groups = securityService.getGroups(userID);
       Iterator<Group> groupList = groups.getGroups().iterator();
       return validateGroup(groupList);
   }
   public SecurityService getSecurityService(){
       return securityService;
   }
   public void setSecurityService(SecurityService securityService){
       this.securityService = securityService;
   }
```

Error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'racfGroup': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.security.client.services.SecurityService com.trac.verification.RacfGroupData.securityService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.security.client.services.SecurityService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: name
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:320)
... 98 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.security.client.services.SecurityService com.trac.verification.RacfGroupData.securityService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.security.client.services.SecurityService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: name
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
... 106 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.security.client.services.SecurityService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: name
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1076)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1021)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:957)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
... 108 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.security.client.services.SecurityService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: name
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:164)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1069)
... 119 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: name
at feign.Util.checkNotNull(Util.java:99)
at feign.Target$HardCodedTarget.<init>(Target.java:67)
at feign.Target$HardCodedTarget.<init>(Target.java:62)
at feign.Feign$Builder.target(Feign.java:175)
at com.security.client.services.SecurityService.<init>(SecurityService.java:29)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:80)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
... 121 more
```

SecurityService

```
public class SecurityService implements ISecurityService
{
private JacksonDecoder _decoder = new JacksonDecoder();
private SecurityServiceApi _securityServiceApi = Feign.builder()
     .decoder(_decoder)
     .encoder(new JacksonEncoder())
     .target(SecurityServiceApi.class, System.getProperty("securityServicesBaseUrl"));

/**
* @param id
* @param useTestGroups
* @return see overriden class or implemented interface
* @see com.security.client.services.ISecurityService#getUser(java.lang.String, boolean)
*/
@Override
public UserLookupResponse getUser(String id, boolean useTestGroups)
{
  return _securityServiceApi.getUser(id, useTestGroups);
}

/**
 * @param id
 * @param useTestGroups
 * @return see overriden class or implemented interface
 * @see com.security.client.services.ISecurityService#getGroups(java.lang.String, boolean)
 */
@Override
public GroupLookupResponse getGroups(String id, boolean useTestGroups)
{
  return _securityServiceApi.getGroups(id, useTestGroups);
}

/**
* @param id
* @return see overriden class or implemented interface
* @see com.security.client.services.ISecurityService#getUser(java.lang.String)
*/
@Override
public UserLookupResponse getUser(String id)
{
  return getUser(id, false);
}

/**
* @param id
* @param testGroups
* @return see overriden class or implemented interface
* @see com.security.client.services.ISecurityService#getUser(java.lang.String, byte[])
*/
@Override
public UserLookupResponse getUser(String id, byte[] testGroups)
{
  UserLookupRequest userLookupRequest = new UserLookupRequest();
  userLookupRequest.setTestGroupsBase64(Base64.encodeBase64String(testGroups));

  return _securityServiceApi.getUser(id, userLookupRequest);
}

/**
* @param id
* @return see overriden class or implemented interface
* @see com.security.client.services.ISecurityService#getGroups(java.lang.String)
*/
@Override
public GroupLookupResponse getGroups(String id)
{
  return getGroups(id, false);
}

/**
* @param id
* @param groups
* @return see overriden class or implemented interface
* @see com.security.client.services.ISecurityService#updateGroups(java.lang.String, java.util.List)
*/
@Override
public void updateGroups(String id, List<Group> groups)
{
  _securityServiceApi.updateGroups(id, createGroupUpdateRequest(groups));
}

/**
* @param id
* @param groups see overriden class or implemented interface
* @see com.security.client.services.ISecurityService#addGroups(java.lang.String, java.util.List)
*/
@Override
public void addGroups(String id, List<Group> groups)
{
  _securityServiceApi.addGroups(id, createGroupUpdateRequest(groups));
}

/**
* @param id
* @param groupName see overriden class or implemented interface
* @see com.security.client.services.ISecurityService#removeGroup(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
*/
@Override
public void removeGroup(String id, String groupName)
{
  _securityServiceApi.removeGroup(id, groupName);

}

private GroupUpdateRequest createGroupUpdateRequest(List<Group> groups)
{
  GroupUpdateRequest groupUpdateRequest = new GroupUpdateRequest();
  groupUpdateRequest.getGroups().addAll(groups);

  return groupUpdateRequest;
}
```

The SecurityClient bean comes from a jar called security-client-0.jar.  Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Where are you getting NPE ?

Comment: EDIT: forgot to add the Error Log.

Comment: Exception is coming from `SecurityService` class. You should add code for that. There's some object not set and throwing NPE in SecurityService's constructor. Also as @kakashi hatake pointed out, you should autowire `ReacfGroupData` in `MainController` as it's controller method will throw NPE when called. But current exception is because of SecurityService not being properly initialized.

Answer (score 1):

you missed injection in `MainController.java` for `private RacfGroupData racfGroup;`  you need to `Autowired` both for each beans.

use this

```
@Autowired
private SessionBean session;
@Autowired
private RacfGroupData racfGroup;
```

refactor in `SecurityService.class` this lines

```
private JacksonDecoder _decoder = new JacksonDecoder();
private SecurityServiceApi _securityServiceApi = Feign.builder()
     .decoder(_decoder)
     .encoder(new JacksonEncoder())
     .target(SecurityServiceApi.class, System.getProperty("securityServicesBaseUrl"));
```

with this

```
@Autowired
private JacksonDecoder _decoder;

private SecurityServiceApi _securityServiceApi;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
 _securityServiceApi = Feign.builder()
         .decoder(_decoder)
         .encoder(new JacksonEncoder())
         .target(SecurityServiceApi.class, System.getProperty("securityServicesBaseUrl"));
}
```

Comment: I did as you suggested but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: you also add default constructor in SecurityService.class add RacfGroupData.class , also @Autowired dependency in SecurityService.class

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  I'm kind of new to using Spring beans to instantiate a class.  The SecurityService is a jar that I am importing into my project and trying to access using a bean.  Where should I add the constructor?

Comment: Plase post SecurityService class

Comment: EDIT: SecurityService class is now added

Comment: @Karson074 I edieted my answer

Comment: I am unable to make any changes to SecurityService.class as it is part of a jar I am importing into my project.

Comment: then your xml bean creation not correct for securityService. its need to some other property

Answer (score 0):

My anwser might not be relevant anymore (4 years too late), but maybe helps anyways.

Had same problem. Checked stacktrace where the Exception was thrown.
In my case the Feign Builder used the URL as the name.

The URL was empty and so was the name, hence the exception.

Your method call `System.getProperty("securityServicesBaseUrl")` must have resulted in an empty string.